# How to install skype?

Tags: skype

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04, 64 bit. I have tried commands and installing skype directly from the internet, it does not happen. 
In laymen's term with detailed description can anyone please help me install Skype on my device?

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question as to describe what exactly you have tried? I.e. what commands you entered etc.

Answer (score 0):

Download the 12.04 multiarch version from [here](http://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/skype-for-linux/)
then you can both double click on it or execute from the Download folder

> sudo dpkg -i skype-ubuntu...

you can just type skype then press tab

Answer (score 0):

Download Skype for Linux in http://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/skype-for-linux/, choose multiarch, install the deb version (Using `sudo dpkg -i skypefile.deb`) and after it push it all by using `sudo apt-get -f install` .

It will install the necessaries programs.

If you failed with multiarch, you can choose the 32 bit and do the same, it will install 32 bit libraries.